# C - How to correctly use SIGUSR1?

Tags: c, process, signals

I've googled far and wide and have come across no CLEAR instructions on how to use a user-defined signal (SIGUSR1/SIGUSR2).

Context: I am trying to send a signal within the running process so that once the signal is sent, the signal handler will print a statement to tell the user that the signal has been caught. I have tried to use a signal handler as shown below.

```
void signalHandler(int signalNum) {
  if (signalNum == SIGUSR1) {
    printf("Caught SIGUSR1 signal.\n");
  }
}

/* Call in main as follows */
signal(SIGUSR1, signalHandler);
```

Now from what I understand, it is possible to raise a signal within a process by using the raise() function which I have tried (I'm trying to do the following WITHOUT forking or using subsequent child/parent processses). When taking the approach that I have shown above, the program never executes any of the code inside the signal handler function, even if it is a print statement before the if statement.

Following this, I have also tried:

```
signalHandler(raise(SIGUSR1));
```

Forgive if my approaches are forbidden, I come from a Python background. Thanks!

EDIT: I need the program to autonomously signal itself, catch the signal, print the message THEN cease executing. No use of the CLI.

Comment: See [kill](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) and [signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, I have read the man7 documentation for both and have been successful in terminating my process using these calls but I need to be able to print the message rather than abruptly ending execution.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send signals to a process using the [`kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) command. The list of all the signals is available on the [`signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man-page.

You can identify the `pid` of your process using the `ps` command and send the signal as

```
kill -10 <pid>
```

This is the method if you want to send the signal externally from the terminal. If you want the process itself to send the signal (or raise the signal), you can use [`raise`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/raise.3.html) as -

```
raise(SIGUSR1);
```

The demo for the same is [here](https://ideone.com/LaVj6e).

If you want to send the signal from another process programmatically you can use `kill` as -

```
kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
```

Comment: Hey Ajay,

 I have read the man7 documentation for both and have been successful in terminating my process using these calls but I need to be able to print the message rather than abruptly ending execution.

I need the program to autonomously signal itself, catch the signal, print the message THEN cease executing. No use of the CLI.

Comment: @cookie, the `-10` will make `kill` send the `SIGUSR1` which will not abruptly end the process. Your handler will be invoked.

Comment: @cookie, I have edited my answer on how a process can send the signal to itself without a CLI.

Comment: thanks! I believe I was just going about this the wrong way. I didn't realise that I had to raise the signal after using the signal() system call. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @cookie, to elaborate on this, the `signal` system call registers a function as a handler with a particular signal level. And raise actually sends the signal. If you send the signal before registering the handler, it will be handled by the default OS handler, which just ignores the `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` and hence you don't see anything